# java EE adding entry...logical problem?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am new at Java EE and still not familiar with it.

We are instructed to save an entry using HashMap, but my **Problem is I don't know how to let a Class read few Strings from my Servlet**

this is my **Servelet Code**:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class AddData extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String id = request.getParameter("newid");
        String name = request.getParameter("newStockName");
        String uprice = request.getParameter("newUPrice");
        String onStock = request.getParameter("newOnStock");

        DataServClass service = new DataServClass();

        /*I am planning to call a method from my DataServClass
          like:
          Item item = service.AddData(id);
          --> not really sure with what i am doing <--
        */

    }
}
```

this is my **DataServClass**:

```
public class DataServClass {
    HashMap itemList = new HashMap();
    public DataServClass() {
        itemList.put("BPEN", new Item( "BPEN", "Ballpen", 5.50, 400 ));
        itemList.put("BONDA4", new Item( "BONDA4", "A4 BondPaper", 250.00, 35 ));
        itemList.put("PCLIP22", new Item( "PCLIP22", "PaperClip No.22", 15, 30 ));
        itemList.put("CD", new Item( "CD", "Blank CD", 4.50, 550 ));

    }
    public void AddData(){
        /*this is what i am planning to do but don't know what to key should i replace with  
          "this"
          --> itemList.put(this, this);
         */
    }

    public Item retrieveData(String id) {
        if (itemList.containsKey(id)) {
            Item item = (Item) itemList.get(id);
            return item;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am also thinking of the usage of session... but still no idea how to declare it... Hope you can help me... thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things not clear. For instance:

> save an entry using HashMap

What does "save" means in this context? Persist this value in some database? Also, it's not clear why you want to use a session.

Anyway, to add the "item" you have in your servlet to your itemList, you can do this:

```
// in servlet
Item item = new Item(id, name, unprice, onStock);
service.AddData(item);

// in your DataServClass
public void AddData(Item item){
  itemList.put(item.getId(), item);
}
```

A non-related note: please, try to follow the Java naming conventions (like, methods starting with lower case). You can also omit the "Class" part of your class DataServClass ;-)